# Not creating and loading .JSON file c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, load, json-deserialization

I am trying to load existing `.json` files at the beginning of my program if they already exist and create them if they don't exist. It was working when I first used it but now that I have split my program into tiers, it has stopped working. Can anyone see as to why this may be happening?

```
public static void ConvertStudentsToJson()
{
     var studentsgrades = ClassOfStudents.Students.Select(x => new { x.StudentName, x.StudentId, x.GradesRecord });

     JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
     serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

     using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\Grades.Data\bin\Debug\StudentsGrades.JSON"))
     {
        using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
        {
             writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
             serializer.Serialize(writer, studentsgrades);
             writer.Close();
             sw.Close();
         }
     }
}

public static void LoadJson()
{
   //loading students grades
 if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\Grades.Data\bin\Debug\StudentsGrades.JSON"))
 {
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\Grades.Data\bin\Debug\StudentsGrades.JSON"))
       {
         string json = r.ReadToEnd();
         ClassOfStudents.Students = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Student>>(json);
         r.Close();
        }
  }
  else
  {              
  File.Create(@"C:\Users\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\Grades.Data\bin\Debug\StudentsGrades.JSON");
   }
  }
```

ClassOfStudents class is as below:

```
public class ClassOfStudents
    {
        public List<Student> Students = new List<Student>();

        public List<Subject> Subjects = new List<Subject>();

        public void AddSubject(Subject subjectName)
        {
            Subjects.Add(subjectName);
        }
        public void AddStudent(Student studentName)
        {
            Students.Add(studentName);
        }
    }
```

subject class is as below:

```
public class Subject
    {
        public string SubjectName { get; set; }
        public Guid SubjectId { get; set; }

        public int MaxMarkAvail;

    }
```

In my program.cs, I have initialised the classofstudents as follows:

`public static ClassOfStudents ClassOfStudents = new ClassOfStudents();`

When I want to view my subjects this method is called:

```
 public static void ViewSubjectsPool()
        {
            Console.Write(Line);
            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease find updated subjects pool below");
            Console.Write(Line + "\n");
            foreach (var subjectname in ClassOfStudents.Subjects)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Subject Id: " + subjectname.SubjectId + "| Subject Name: " + subjectname.SubjectName + "| Max Available Mark = " + subjectname.MaxMarkAvail);
            }
            Console.Write(Line + "\n\n");
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the exception you get?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I dont get any exception, the data doesn't load and save

Comment: When you attach the debugger and run it, does it execute the branches of your if and the methods that you expect it to?

Comment: @AdamG yes, it goes through the if statements

Comment: So which of the above lines isn't producing the desired side effect on your file system?

Comment: @AdamG the code inside the if statement that should run when the file already exists in LoadJSon() method. Its supposed to read the file and deserialize the data. The serialize bit in convertoJSON method doesn't work either

Comment: So does the  string json = r.ReadToEnd();. line put a value into the json variable there? Does it contain what you expect it to?

Comment: @AdamG yes when it deserilises, it contains the data from the file

Comment: Have you called your ClassOfStudents variable "ClassOfStudents" too? That'll trip you up for sure. How is that field/property/variable declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there isn't much one can tell you given the information, what's useful here is the troubleshooting you can do to figure this out. More importantly, troubleshooting your code is a skill/art that takes time to develop, so this is an excellent opportunity for you.

I would break this up into several excercises, since you're not sure where the error is.

1. Test your load method - make sure you have a valid JSON file (from your time when it worked) stored in that path, set a breakpoint on your load method, and step through it. Once you do, you'll know if the file failed to load (one point of failure, for example UAC wont allow you access), if that works, does your raw json look as you expect it (in VS IDE you can just hover over it or use the immediate window. If that's ok, does your deserialize method return the expected object structure?
2. Test your save method. Add a breakpoint, call save with actual results, knowing expected results. Then as you step through your code, you can find the failing statement, and focus your troubleshooting efforts there.

Side not, add some try/catch statements (I don't know what sort of error handling you have now) that would (at least) trap the error and write it to the console. That way, if you get an error here in the future, you'll know where to look.